# Get data from <td> on the same table row specified by row id and perform computation

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have an html table populated by data coming from a mysql database. This is the structure:

```
<table>    
<?php
foreach($prods as $key=>$p){
?>
   <tr class="row1" id="tr<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>">
   <td id="pid<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>"><?php echo $p['ProductID']?></td>
   <td id="pname<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>"><?php echo $p['ProductName'];?></td>
   <td id="pdesc<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>"><?php echo $p['ProductDesc'];?></td>
   <td id="pprice<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>"><?php echo $p['UnitPrice'];?></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>" checked></td>
   <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;" onkeyup="getall(this);" id="<?php echo    $p['ProductID']?>"></td>
   <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;" id="total<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>">    </td>
   <span id="ttl" name="ttl"> 0.00</span>
   </tr>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
   </table>
```

I don't have issues populating the table, however I need to update the `<span id="ttl">` value, every time the user changes the value of the `<input type="text" style="width:50px;" onkeyup="getall(this);" id="<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>"></td>`. I made a Javascript function but I fail doing what I want.

The value of the span should be the product of `<td id="pprice<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>"><?php echo $p['UnitPrice'];?></td>` and the quantity entered by the user at the textbox.

I will soon save these data back into the database once all fields are filled.

Comment: And the _failing_ javascript function looks like what?

Comment: I stopped in trying to get the id of the textbox
function getall( myobj){
 var bid = myobj.getAttribute('id');// button ID 
 alert("Hi " + bid + " "+ppid);

}

Comment: i really don't know what to do... all I know is i have to get each of the <td> values so i can facilitate the computation and assign the answer as the value of the <span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if **this** is used correctly. Just try something like:

```
<input type="text" style="width:50px;" onkeyup="getall('<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>');" id="<?php echo $p['ProductID']?>"></td>
```

And in your javascript function:

```
function getall(strId)
{
    var tmpObj = document.getElementById(strId);
    alert("reported id for testing: " + tmpObj.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Try that.

Comment: ok i tried it, and it works...thank you for that. How about using all the data from that row for the computation?

Comment: @1947676 Put the id of the row instead of the id of the input and then search inside the row for the data you need for the computation.

Comment: I tried

var $row = $(strId).parents('tr'); 
                alert($row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
                alert($row.find('td:eq(2)').html());
to get the values of each but it returns undefined

Comment: Oh, now I got it! Thanks @user2553780.
function getall( strId){
 var tmpObj = document.getElementById(strId);
 var myobj = $("#listOfProducts").find("tr#" + strId);
    alert("reported id for testing: " + tmpObj.getAttribute("id"));
 
                    alert(myobj.find('td:eq(0)').html());
     alert(myobj.find('td:eq(1)').html());
                    alert(myobj.find('td:eq(2)').html());
     alert(myobj.find('td:eq(3)').html());
     alert(myobj.find('td:eq(5) input').val());

}